# Android: Animate Custom Drawable programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have a Custom Class extending Drawable as seen below which is meant to draw an Arc. From my MainActivity controlling the Drawable, I am redrawing it based on some input values that I translate to the appropriate "angle" for the shape. E.g.

This is the initial state of the drawable:
[image]

This is the second state of the drawable: [image]
*Red arrow indicates the motion i am trying to achieve*

I am trying to "animate" the change from state 1 to state 2 with a sweeping motion. Any ideas on how to do that? Should I redraw the shape a number of times gradually transitioning between state one and two?

My Drawable Code:

```
public class CircleLoadingBar extends Drawable implements Drawable.Callback{

private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private float angle;
private RectF outterCircle;
private float padding=30;

public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable){
    final Callback callback = getCallback();
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.invalidateDrawable(this);
    }
}

public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable drawable, Runnable runnable, long l){
    invalidateDrawable(drawable);
}

public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable drawable,Runnable runnable){
    //empty
}

public CircleLoadingBar(){
    this(0);
}

public CircleLoadingBar( int angle){
    this.angle=angle;
    this.canvas=new Canvas();

    paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(padding);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    outterCircle = new RectF();
}

public void setAngle(float angle){
    this.angle=angle;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){

    canvas.save();

    Rect bounds = getBounds();

    outterCircle.set(bounds.left+padding,bounds.top+padding,bounds.right-padding,bounds.bottom-padding);

    int[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.RED};
    float[] positions = {0,0.2f,1.3f};
    SweepGradient gradient3 = new SweepGradient(innerCircle.centerX(), innerCircle.centerY(),colors,positions);

    paint.setShader(gradient3);

    canvas.drawArc(outterCircle,90,angle,true,paint);

}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // Has no effect
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    // Has no effect
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    // Not Implemented
    return 0;
}
}
```

My MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    circleLoadingBar= new CircleLoadingBar(10);
    textView.setBackgroundDrawable(circleLoadingBar);

}

  public void stateUpdate(float angle) {

        circleLoadingBar.setAngle(angle);
        textView.invalidate();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, I found the answer.

**Summary:** 
I needed my Custom Drawable class to implement Drawable.Callback and Runnable interfaces (see code below).

*CustomDrawable.class*

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable implements Drawable.Callback, Runnable{

    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private int angle;
    private RectF circle;
    private float cx,cy;
    private float mHeight,mWidth=100;
    private float mRadius=20;
    private Drawable.Callback cb;
    private boolean running=false;


    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable){
        super.invalidateSelf(); //This was done for my specific example. I wouldn't use it otherwise
    }


    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable drawable, Runnable runnable, long l){
        invalidateDrawable(drawable);
    }

    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable drawable,Runnable runnable){
        super.unscheduleSelf(runnable);
    }

    public CircleLoadingBar(){
        this(0);
    }

    public CircleLoadingBar(int angle){
        this.angle=angle;

        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        circle= new RectF();
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

        canvas.save();

        Rect bounds = getBounds();

        circle.set(bounds);
        canvas.drawArc(circle, 90, angle, true, paint);

    }

    public void nextFrame(){
        unscheduleSelf(this);
        scheduleSelf(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 250);
    }

    public void stop(){
        running=false;
        unscheduleSelf(this);
    }

    public void start(){
        if(!running){
            running=true;
            nextFrame();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        angle++;
        invalidate();
        nextFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        // Has no effect
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        // Has no effect
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        // Not Implemented
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

Now that your Drawable implements both, you can just "run" it as a separate thread, initiated and controlled by your activity via start and stop functions.

Comment: `angle++` that means the drawable falls behind if the UI thread gets delayed. It's usually better to take into account how much time passed between frames, rather than assuming there's always 60 fps.